# Constraining an operation by matching a type parameter to an argument's path-dependent type

Tags: scala, type-parameter, type-constraints, path-dependent-type

I would like to exploit Scala's type system to constrain operations in a system where there are versioned references to some values. This is all happening in some transactional context `Ctx` which has a version type `V` attached to it. Now there is a `Factory` to create reference variables. They get created with a *creation* version attached them (type parameter `V1`), corresponding to the version of the context in which the factory was called.

Now imagine that some code tries to access that reference in a *later* version, that is using a different `Ctx`. What I want to achieve is that it is prohibited to call access on that `Ref` in any version (`Ctx`'s `V` type field) that doesn't match the creation version, but that you are allowed to resolve the reference by some substitution mechanism that returns a new view of the `Ref` which can be accessed in the current version. (it's ok if `substitute` is called with an invalid context, e.g. one that is older than the `Ref`'s `V1` -- in that case a runtime exception could be thrown)

Here is my attempt:

```
trait Version

trait Ctx {
  type V <: Version
}

object Ref {
  implicit def access[C <: Ctx, R, T](r: R)(implicit c: C, view: R => Ref[C#V, T]): T =
    view(r).access(c)

  implicit def substitute[C <: Ctx, T](r: Ref[_ <: Version, T])
                                      (implicit c: C): Ref[C#V, T] = r.substitute(c)
}
trait Ref[V1 <: Version, T] {
  def access(implicit c: { type V = V1 }): T // ???
  def substitute[C <: Ctx](implicit c: C): Ref[C#V, T]
}

trait Factory {
  def makeRef[C <: Ctx, T](init: T)(implicit c: C): Ref[C#V, T]
}
```

And the problem is to define class method `access` in a way that the whole thing compiles, i.e. the compound object's `access` should compile, but at the same time that I cannot call this class method `access` with *any* `Ctx`, only with one whose version matches the reference's version.

Preferably without structural typing or anything that imposes performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, and to close the question, here is another idea that I like because the client code is fairly clutter free:

```
trait System[A <: Access[_]] {
  def in[T](v: Version)(fun: A => T): T
}

trait Access[Repr] {
  def version: Version
  def meld[R[_]](v: Version)(fun: Repr => Ref[_, R]): R[this.type]
}

trait Version

trait Ref[A, Repr[_]] {
  def sub[B](b: B): Repr[B]
}

object MyRef {
  def apply[A <: MyAccess](implicit a: A): MyRef[A] = new Impl[A](a)

  private class Impl[A](a: A) extends MyRef[A] {
    def sub[B](b: B) = new Impl[B](b)
    def schnuppi(implicit ev: A <:< MyAccess) = a.gagaism
  }
}
trait MyRef[A] extends Ref[A, MyRef] {
  // this is how we get MyAccess specific functionality
  // in here without getting trapped in more type parameters
  // in all the traits
  def schnuppi(implicit ev: A <:< MyAccess): Int
}

trait MyAccess extends Access[MyAccess] {
  var head: MyRef[this.type]
  var tail: MyRef[this.type]
  def gagaism: Int
}

def test(sys: System[MyAccess], v0: Version, v1: Version): Unit = {
  val v2 = sys.in(v0) { a => a.tail = a.meld(v1)(_.head); a.version }
  val a3 = sys.in(v2) { a => a }
  val (v4, a4) = sys.in(v1) { a =>
    a.head = a.head
    println(a.head.schnuppi) // yes!
    (a.version, a)
  }
  // a3.head = a4.head // forbidden
}
```

Comment: To the impertinent "moderators" here on SO - this is my accepted answer because it is a sort of _solution_ to my question. Downvote yourself if it makes you feel better.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

```
trait Version

trait Ctx[+V1 <: Version] {
  type V = V1
}

type AnyCtx   = Ctx[_ <: Version]
type AnyRf[T] = Ref[_ <: Version, T]

object Ref {
  implicit def access[C <: AnyCtx, R, T](r: R)(
    implicit c: C, view: R => Ref[C#V, T]): T = view(r).access(c)

  implicit def substitute[C <: AnyCtx, T](r: AnyRf[T])(implicit c: C): Ref[C#V, T] =
    r.substitute( c )
}
trait Ref[V1 <: Version, T] {
  def access(implicit c: Ctx[V1]): T
  def substitute[C <: AnyCtx](implicit c: C): Ref[C#V, T]
}

trait Factory {
  def makeVar[C <: AnyCtx, T](init: T)(implicit c: C): Ref[C#V, T]
}

// def shouldCompile1(r: AnyRf[String])(implicit c: AnyCtx): String = r

def shouldCompile2(r: AnyRf[String])(implicit c: AnyCtx): String = {
  val r1 = Ref.substitute(r)
  r1.access(c)
}

// def shouldFail(r: AnyRf[String])(implicit c: AnyCtx): String = r.access(c)
```

So the follow-up questions are

1. why I need a redundancy of the type
   parameter for `Ctx` to achieve this. I hate that these type 
   parameters accumulate like rabbits in my code.
2. why `shouldCompile1` doesn't compile
   —can i get the implicits to work as planned?

**EDIT:**

This is *wrong*, too. The variance annotation is wrong. Because now the following compiles although it shouldn't:

```
def versionStep(c: AnyCtx): AnyCtx = c // no importa

def shouldFail3[C <: AnyCtx](f: Factory, c: C): String = {
  val r    = f.makeVar("Hallo")(c)
  val c2   = versionStep(c)
  r.access(c2)
}
```