# Variance trick with path-dependent types

Tags: scala, implicit, variance, path-dependent-type

Here's another one for implicits and path dependent types. I don't understand why I need to be so verbose here: (Note -- I found the answer, see below)

```
trait B
trait C[X]
trait A { def call[B1 <: B](implicit b: B1): C[B1] }
trait D extends B {
  def set(c: C[this.type]): Unit
}
```

first try:

```
def test1(a: A)(implicit d: D: Unit =
  d.set(a.call) // found C[D] -- required C[d.type]
```

second try:

```
def test2(a: A)(implicit d: D): Unit =
  d.set(a.call[d.type]) // could not find implicit value for parameter b: d.type
```

third try:

```
def test3(a: A)(implicit d: D): Unit =
  d.set(a.call[d.type](d))  // works. why so much clutter!?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Scala 2.9 REPL helps us (thanks, whoever added this useful message!). Here for the `test1`:

```
 found   : C[D]
 required: C[d.type]
Note: D >: d.type, but trait C is invariant in type X.
You may wish to define X as -X instead. (SLS 4.5)
              d.set( a.call ) // found C[D] -- required C[d.type]
                       ^
```

Thus: changing `trait C[ X ]` to `trait C[ -X ]` makes `test1` work as expected.

Comment: That doesn't mean you _want_ `C` to be contra-variant.  `d.type` is a more specific type than `D` -- it is a singleton type of each instance.

Comment: In fact, it didn't take long till I ran into the next wall where X was necessarily used in an invariant position. How come this type constraints stuff is such a PITA

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want `this.type`? Scala's "this type" is not the same as what is more commonly known as "[MyType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962219/mytype-problem-do-i-have-to-use-abstract-types-or-generics-in-scala-to-retur)". See [this discussion](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/this-type-doesn-t-mean-what-I-think-it-does-td2269225.html) on `this.type`, as well as the discussion linked by the MyType question.

Comment: Yes I do want it; the reason is I want to constrain operations to one particular context. Some of the elaborations of this can be found in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524595/constraining-an-operation-by-matching-a-type-parameter-to-an-arguments-path-depe