# Defining a method whose return type is the singleton type of an argument of that method

Tags: scala, types, singleton

Still struggling with this.types (singleton types). Assume this scenario:

```
trait Sys[A <: Access] {
  def in[T](v: String): AccessPrepare[A]
}

trait AccessPrepare[A <: Access] {
  val a: A
  def apply[T](fun: a.type => T): T
}

object Ref {
  def single[A <: Access, V](v: V)(implicit a: A): Ref[A, V] = ???
}
trait Ref[A, V]

trait Access {
  def set(r: Ref[this.type, Int]): Unit
}
```

The following fails:

```
def test(sys: Sys[Access]): Unit =
  sys.in("v1") { implicit a =>
    val r = Ref.single(44)
    a.set(r)
  }
```

because apparently `r` is of type `Ref[Access, Int]` and not `Ref[a.type, Int]`. My guess is the problem is that I would need a line like

```
def single[A <: Access, V](v: V)(implicit a: A): Ref[a.type, V] = ...
```

which isn't compiling as due to "illegal dependent method type"...

Any ideas how I can fix this. The demand is that I do not explicitly annotate calls with types. That is, I do *not* want to write `Ref.single[a.type, Int](44)(a)` for comprehensible reasons.

---

**EDIT**

As a clarification, with reference to answer "FYI, and to close the question" in thread [Constraining an operation by matching a type parameter to an argument's path-dependent type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524595/constraining-an-operation-by-matching-a-type-parameter-to-an-arguments-path-depe) -- what I would like to have in addition is the possibility to create objects (Refs) not by using a factory method *in the* Access but somewhere outside (e.g. with a `new` statement). Because the system cannot be limited by the definition of Access, I must be able to extend it with further objects.

Comment: I added another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575030/driving-a-singleton-type-through-a-brickwall -- I think if I can solve that one, this one will also be solved as a consequence (I hope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several possibilities. With Scala 2.8/2.8.1, you can use the private option `-Ydependent-method-types` and then your solution with

```
def single[ A <: Access, V ]( v: V )( implicit a: A ) : Ref[ a.type, V ] = // ...
```

compiles fine.

If you want to avoid dependent method types because it's a private option, you can still make your first proposal compile by explicitly typing the call to `Ref.single`:

```
  val r = Ref.single[a.type, Int](44)
```

You need to specify the type, though, as singleton types are never inferred. You problem is not the same as, but related to, the problem that singleton types are not inferred: see [How to correctly type-annotate this HList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907727/how-to-correctly-type-annotate-this-hlist/3909655#3909655)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. First time I hear o the dependent-method-types option. So the type system _can_ handle it. I wonder if this going to be activated or made public in future Scala versions?