# Driving a singleton type through a brickwall

Tags: scala, types, path-dependent-type

Here is a very condensed version:

```
case class Brickwall[A](otherSide: A)
trait Monoman { def me(m: this.type): Unit }

def test(m: Monoman): Unit = m.me(Brickwall(m).otherSide)

-> error: type mismatch;
 found   : Monoman
 required: m.type
```

stupid brickwall doesn't let me through. any ideas how it might be possible? secret scala tunnel effects? hoping...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know the Scala compiler refuses to infer path dependent types, so a little type annotation helps:

```
def test( m: Monoman ) { m.me( Brickwall[m.type]( m ).otherSide )}
```

Comment: thanks moritz. hmmm, yes, i should have said that i'm trying to get around forcing the user-side of my framework to be writing exactly this, m.type... it's a DSL and i don't want to see any explicit typing at all if possible. trying to find a solution to constrain references to a unique context so they cannot escape. Have found a very interesting paper by philipp haller and martin odersky (i've seen it before but didn't pay attention) : http://lamp.epfl.ch/~phaller/capabilities.html -- it may be that i just need to settle with the idea that what i want is not possible without compiler plugins

Answer (score 3):

Yes, singleton types are never inferred by the Scala compiler.

One possibility is to add a factory method to the Monoman trait:

```
trait Monoman { 
  def me( m: this.type ) : Unit
  def createWall = Brickwall[this.type](this) 
}

def test( m: Monoman ) { m.me(m.createWall.otherSide) }
```

Maybe that's not a viable solution in your case.

Comment: yes, I had done this before, but I was actually looking to be able to get any class into my system, e.g. using `new`, because the system shouldn't be required to know every possible class in advance, it should be extensible "from the ouside". i could still use one type as a wrapper, e.g. `Ref` and then do implicit wrapping and unwrapping of any type. I'll try to see if I can come up with an example to see if this works transparently.; sorry there is only one "accept" option, you two both deserve it.

Comment: A workable, but ugly solution is to add a generic factory in Monoman: `def create[M[_]](implicit f : Monoman => M[Monoman]) = f(this).asInstanceOf[M[this.type]]`

Answer (score 1):

here is a try with the factory idea (i had done this before and gave up, but well let's try again):

```
object Brickwall
case class Brickwall[A](brick: A)

trait Monoman { 
  var wall: Ref[this.type, Brickwall[String]]
  def ref[V](v: V): Ref[this.type, V]
}

object Ref {
  implicit def unwrap[Repr](r: Ref[_, Repr]): Repr = r.repr
  implicit def wrap[A, Repr](repr: Repr): Ref[A, Repr] = new Impl[A, Repr](repr)
  private class Impl[A, Repr](val repr: Repr) extends Ref[A, Repr]
}
trait Ref[A, Repr] { def repr: Repr }

def test(m: Monoman): Unit = {
  val w0 = m.wall
  val w1 = w0.copy(brick = "3.1415")
  m.wall = w1 // doesn't convert to Ref
}
```

so while the unwrapping is transparent, the re-wrapping doesn't seem to be working, and i suspect it's not possible to get it working, again because `m.type` can never be inferred.