# Relationship between this and this.type

Tags: scala

The following:

```
trait Foo {
    type T
    val foo: T
}

trait Bar extends Foo {
    type T = this.type
    val foo = this
}
```

gives the compiler error:

```
<console>:8: error: overriding value foo in trait Foo of type Bar.this.T;
 value foo has incompatible type
        val foo = this
            ^
```

However, if I change the last line to:

```
val foo: this.type = this
```

it compiles without error.

Why do I have to specify the type explicitly here? I've already said the the type of `foo` should be `T` and that `T` should be `this.type`. Is the type of `this` not  `this.type`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Scala compiler never automatically infers singleton types like `this.type`. They are somehow “too specific” and would lead to strange behaviors in other more common situations.

On the same topic, see also:

- [Scala this.type conformance to type parameter bounds of supertype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886182/scala-this-type-conformance-to-type-parameter-bounds-of-supertype)
- [Defining a method whose return type is the singleton type of an argument of that method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574687/defining-a-method-whose-return-type-is-the-singleton-type-of-an-argument-of-that)
- [Scala abstract type representing type of subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871207/scala-abstract-type-representing-type-of-subclass)
- [Driving a singleton type through a brickwall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575030/driving-a-singleton-type-through-a-brickwall/5577655#5577655)
- [How to correctly type-annotate this HList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907727/how-to-correctly-type-annotate-this-hlist/3909655#3909655)
- [Singleton types are mean and spiteful](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.user/27515/focus=27555)